# How to render readable a large TeXForm expression from Mathematica

Tags: math-mode, formatting, wolfram-mathematica, rendering

I am using

```
\documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
```

I'd like to know how to incorporate either of the following two forms 
(TraditionalForm and StandardForm) produced by Mathematica into my document
in some readable form (one in which material is not lost--like overflowing lines)

Mathematica provides me (using TradtionalForm) the code

```
\frac{1}{250} \left(50 (2 k+7)+\sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} \left(-3 \sin \left(\frac{2}{5} \pi 
   (1-2 k)\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{4 \pi  k}{5}\right)-2 \sin \left(\frac{6 \pi 
   k}{5}\right)-3 \sin \left(\frac{1}{5} (\pi -6 \pi  k)\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{5}
   (\pi -4 \pi  k)\right)-3 \left(\sin \left(\frac{2}{5} (3 \pi  k+\pi )\right)+\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{5} (4 \pi  k+\pi )\right)\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{5} (6 \pi  k+\pi
   )\right)\right)+\sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} \left(-2 \sin \left(\frac{2}{5} \pi 
   (1-4 k)\right)-2 \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{5}\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{8 \pi 
   k}{5}\right)-2 \sin \left(\frac{2}{5} \pi  (k+1)\right)-3 \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{5}
   (\pi -2 \pi  k)\right)-\sin \left(\frac{2}{5} (4 \pi  k+\pi )\right)+\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{5} (8 \pi  k+\pi )\right)\right)+3 \cos \left(\frac{1}{10} (4 \pi 
   k+\pi )\right)\right)\right)
```

or (using StandardForm)

```
\frac{1}{250} \left(50 (7+2 k)+\sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} \left(-3 \text{Sin}\left[\frac{2}{5}
   (1-2 k) \pi \right]+2 \text{Sin}\left[\frac{4 k \pi }{5}\right]-2
   \text{Sin}\left[\frac{6 k \pi }{5}\right]-3 \text{Sin}\left[\frac{1}{5} (\pi -6 k \pi
   )\right]+2 \text{Sin}\left[\frac{1}{5} (\pi -4 k \pi )\right]-3
   \left(\text{Sin}\left[\frac{2}{5} (\pi +3 k \pi )\right]+\text{Sin}\left[\frac{1}{5}
   (\pi +4 k \pi )\right]\right)+2 \text{Sin}\left[\frac{1}{5} (\pi +6 k \pi
   )\right]\right)+\sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} \left(3 \text{Cos}\left[\frac{1}{10}
   (\pi +4 k \pi )\right]-2 \text{Sin}\left[\frac{2}{5} (1-4 k) \pi \right]-2
   \text{Sin}\left[\frac{2 k \pi }{5}\right]+2 \text{Sin}\left[\frac{8 k \pi
   }{5}\right]-2 \text{Sin}\left[\frac{2}{5} (1+k) \pi \right]-3
   \left(\text{Sin}\left[\frac{1}{5} (\pi -2 k \pi )\right]-\text{Sin}\left[\frac{2}{5}
   (\pi +4 k \pi )\right]+\text{Sin}\left[\frac{1}{5} (\pi +8 k \pi
   )\right]\right)\right)\right)
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

\begin{document}

$\let\left\relax\let\right\relax
\frac{1}{250} \left(50 (2 k+7)+\sqrt{50-10 \sqrt{5}} \left(-3 \sin \left(\frac{2}{5} \pi 
   (1-2 k)\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{4 \pi  k}{5}\right)-2 \sin \left(\frac{6 \pi 
   k}{5}\right)-3 \sin \left(\frac{1}{5} (\pi -6 \pi  k)\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{5}
   (\pi -4 \pi  k)\right)-3 \left(\sin \left(\frac{2}{5} (3 \pi  k+\pi )\right)+\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{5} (4 \pi  k+\pi )\right)\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{5} (6 \pi  k+\pi
   )\right)\right)+\sqrt{10 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)} \left(-2 \sin \left(\frac{2}{5} \pi 
   (1-4 k)\right)-2 \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{5}\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{8 \pi 
   k}{5}\right)-2 \sin \left(\frac{2}{5} \pi  (k+1)\right)-3 \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{5}
   (\pi -2 \pi  k)\right)-\sin \left(\frac{2}{5} (4 \pi  k+\pi )\right)+\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{5} (8 \pi  k+\pi )\right)\right)+3 \cos \left(\frac{1}{10} (4 \pi 
   k+\pi )\right)\right)\right)
$

\end{document}
```

having got it to fit you can of course tinker with the layout, you may prefer `\displaystyle` or to put it in `begin{center}..\end{center}` or to fake an equation number by ending `..$\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)` etc.